# Nodejs user leaves page prematurely

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

What happens to nodejs process behind reverse proxy if I just send ajax request in background, and user leaves/closes page, before it gets confirmation from nodejs script that process is done?

Does it continue to work, and finish async loop, for example, or it just terminates and stops at error handler? Leaving data half-way done?

Comment: I think the presence of a reverse proxy is irrelevant.  Or maybe you are troubleshooting hung processes in it.  But I like the question :D.  You could check the logs for whatever you are using as the web-server in Node.js.

Comment: I guess I'll have to test myself...

Comment: @AleksandarPavić did you find out the answer?

Comment: @SagarChilukuri It depends upon your code. If code is async, do something without further interaction it works. But if you are waiting for user action to commit data, then it will stop there, for example...